# How to reference another DNS entry from a primary zone ( BIND 9 )

Tags: linux, bind9

I have two sub zones lets say:

```
zone "first.com" {                      type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/first.com.primary";};
zone "second.com" {                      type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/second.com.primary";};
```

Inside First I define

```
$TTL 300
@   IN SOA ns1.org.com. postmaster.org.com. (
    2022050902  ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      ns1.org.com.
subdomain                IN A       127.0.0.1
```

In second I want to reference first

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.org.com. postmaster.org.com. (
    2019032601   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      ns1.org.com.

@                        IN CNAME       subdomain.first.com.
www                      IN CNAME       @

localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CNAME` record specifies that the name on the *left* side of the `CNAME` record is an alias of the name on the *right* side - **for all types of DNS records**, not just for `A` records. The bolded bit is what is causing the problem here, because "all record types" also includes the zone's `SOA` and `NS` records.

You're trying to use a `CNAME` record at the apex of the `second.com` zone, where the `SOA` record also lives. So written in a fully-qualified form, your first `CNAME` says:

```
second.com.  IN CNAME subdomain.first.com.
```

As a result, when the SOA record of `second.com` is requested, the SOA record of `subdomain.first.com` should be returned instead. But then the real SOA record of `second.com` will be inaccessible, and without that SOA record, the entire `second.com` domain will be broken - meaning that the `CNAME` record pointing to `subdomain.first.com` is not actually valid.

Also, if `subdomain.first.com` is not the apex of its own zone, but just a subdomain in a higher-level zone, then it has no SOA record of its own: following the CNAME mapping would mean that a request for `second.com`'s SOA record would have to be answered with a "no such record exists, definitely". But if there is no SOA record for the `second.com` zone, then the zone does not exist.

Likewise, when the NS records of `second.com` are requested, the `CNAME` would require responding with the NS records of `subdomain.first.com` instead. But the nameservers of the `subdomain.first.com` are not required to know anything at all about `second.com`.

To prevent paradoxical situations like this, [Section 3.6.2 of RFC 1034 says](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-3.6.2):

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot be different. This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

(Note that RFC 1034 pre-dates the convention to use the words *SHOULD*, *MUST* and *MAY* strictly according to the requirement level, [as defined in RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119). Although it says "no other data *should* be present", this is a requirement, not a recommendation, as the correctness of DNS caching depends on it.)

This rule makes it impossible for a `CNAME` record to live at the apex of a zone, because the `SOA` and `NS` records are required at the apex for the zone to meaningfully exist, and any `CNAME` record together with them would violate this rule.

For more details, see: https://www.isc.org/blogs/cname-at-the-apex-of-a-zone/

---

```
@                        IN CNAME       subdomain.first.com.
www                      IN CNAME       @
```

Also, pointing a `CNAME` record at another `CNAME` record is inefficient and bad style, although it technically works. You should always go directly to the canonical name at the end of the chain:

```
@                        IN CNAME       subdomain.first.com.
www                      IN CNAME       subdomain.first.com.
```